# Validation JSON Golang sobreescribe Headers

Tags: api, go

Estoy intentando usar la libreria Validator de Golang y estoy teniendo problemas para validar un json. Les paso el codigo:

```
type request struct {
    TranCode    string  `json:"tranCode" binding:"required"`
    Currency    string  `json:"currency" binding:"required"`
    Amount      float64 `json:"amount" binding:"required"`
    Transmitter string  `json:"transmitter" binding:"required"`
    Reciever    string  `json:"reciever" binding:"required"`
    TranDate    string  `json:"tranDate" binding:"required"`
}

type Transaction struct {
    service transactions.Service
}

func NewTransaction(s transactions.Service) *Transaction {
    return &Transaction{
        service: s,
    }
}

func (t *Transaction) GetAll() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        token := ctx.Request.Header.Get("token")
        if token != "12345" {
            ctx.JSON(401, gin.H{
                "error": "token inválido",
            })
            return
        }
        t, err := t.service.GetAll()
        if err != nil {
            ctx.JSON(404, gin.H{
                "error": err.Error(),
            })
            return
        }
        ctx.JSON(200, t)
    }
}

func (t *Transaction) Store() gin.HandlerFunc {
    var req request
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        token := ctx.Request.Header.Get("token")
        if token != "12345" {
            ctx.JSON(401, gin.H{"error": " inválido"})
            return
        }

        if err := ctx.Bind(&req); err != nil {
            var ve validator.ValidationErrors
            if errors.As(err, &ve) {
                result := ""
                for i, field := range ve {
                    if i != len(ve)-1 {
                        result += fmt.Sprintf("El campo %s es requerido y ", field.Field())
                    } else {
                        result += fmt.Sprintf("El campo %s es requerido", field.Field())
                    }
                }
                ctx.JSON(404, result)
                return
            }
        }
        t, err := t.service.Store(req.TranCode, req.Currency, req.Amount, req.Transmitter, req.Reciever, req.TranDate)
        if err != nil {
            ctx.JSON(404, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
            return
        }
        ctx.JSON(200, t)
    }
}
```

Si hago el POST en postman de esta manera:

```
{
    "tranCode": "",
    "currency": "2",
    "amount": 10.0,
    "transmitter": "3",
    "reciever": "4",
    "tranDate": "5"
}
```

Me devuelve `{"id":1,"tranCode":"","currency":"2","amount":10,"transmitter":"3","reciever":"4","tranDate":""}`
Y en consola se puede ver "Headers were already wrotten. Wanted to override status code 400 with 200".

Si cambio el return a esta otra linea frena la ejecucion pero obviamente no imprime nada porque result queda fuera de scope

```
  }
                    
                    
                }
          ctx.JSON(404, result)
    
            **return**
            }
            t, err := t.service.Store(req.TranCode, req.Currency, req.Amount,
```

Tengo otra funcion en teoria igual en donde si funciona pero no logro entender por que funciona en un lado si y en otro no.

```
func GenerateTransaction() gin.HandlerFunc {
    var transac Transacciones
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        token := c.GetHeader("token")
        if token != "1234" {
            c.JSON(401, gin.H{
                "error": "No tiene permisos para realizar la peticion solicitada",
            })
            return
        }
        if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&transac); err != nil {
            var ve validator.ValidationErrors
            if errors.As(err, &ve) {
                result := ""
                for i, field := range ve {
                    if i != len(ve)-1 {
                        result += fmt.Sprintf("El campo %s es requerido y ", field.Field())
                    } else {
                        result += fmt.Sprintf("El campo %s es requerido", field.Field())
                    }
                }
                c.JSON(404, result)
                return
            }
        }
        lastID++
        transac.Id = lastID
        t = append(t, transac)
        c.JSON(200, t)
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por si alguien viene con un problema similar le dejo la respuesta: la version que funciona es validator v10

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el error 400 sea generado en la llamada a `Bind`, sugiero que uses esta forma:

```go
        if err := ctx.Bind(&req); err != nil {
            var ve validator.ValidationErrors
            if errors.As(err, &ve) {
                result := ""
                for i, field := range ve {
                    if i != len(ve)-1 {
                        result += fmt.Sprintf("El campo %s es requerido y ", field.Field())
                    } else {
                        result += fmt.Sprintf("El campo %s es requerido", field.Field())
                    }
                }
                ctx.JSON(400, result)
            }
            return
        }
```

También recuerda que el código de error 404 es exclusivo para recursos no encontrados.

Comment: Gracias por tu respueta! Probé con Bind y tambien con ese return y si bien corta la ejecución no se imprime nada. La terminal devuelve un 400, pero pasa por alta el ctx.JSON ponga lo que le ponga